# Need a list of variables inside the registry

Tags: registry

In the Widows registry, there are variables:

```
C:\acme.exe "%V"
```

Would some kind soul please point me to a list of what these variables are?

Many thanks,
-T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php
Check if this helps.
This mentions that %V is a Long fully qualified path of file

Comment: Exactly what I was after.  Thank you!